# c preprocessor macro concatenate arguments after expansion

Tags: c, macros, embedded, avr, atmega

I am writing a driver for avr gpio, I have a function that takes an input which is an enum. I made a macro that calls this function after concatenating the port name with "__" so I can always use initPort(PORTA,1,...).

```
#define initPort(port,mask,dir,pullup) GPIO_Init(port ## __,mask,dir,pullup)

typedef enum {
PORTA__,
PORTB__,
PORTC__,
PORTD__
} PORT;

void GPIO_Init(PORT p, uint8_t pins, Direction dir,uint8_t pullup) {
switch (p) {
    case PORTA__:
```

now when I want to use that function I use: initPort(PORTA,1,...) and this works fine. 
The problem is when I want to use something like:

```
#define LED_PORT PORTA
initPort(LED_PORT,1,...)
```

what happens now is that the argument of GPIO_Init is now LED_PORT__ and not PORTA__

is it possible to fix this or I have to use another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually *can* do it by forcing the preprocessor to perform an extra pass before:

```
#define initPortS(port,mask,dir,pullup) GPIO_Init(port ## __,mask,dir,pullup)
#define initPort(...) initPortS(__VA_ARGS__)
#define LED_PORT PORTA

initPort(LED_PORT,1,2,3);
```

This will do:

**1st pass:**

```
initPort(LED_PORT,1,2,3); -> initPortS(PORTA,1,2,3);
```

**2nd pass:**

```
initPortS(PORTA,1,2,3); -> GPIO_Init(PORTA__,1,2,3);
```

[Here is a demo](https://godbolt.org/g/iAjTgC)

**Possible pitfall:**

If `PORTA` is a defined symbol, it will get expanded too on the second pass. So if you have a line such as

```
#define PORTA XXX
```

somewhere in the code, it will expand into

```
GPIO_Init(XXX__,1,2,3);
```

Comment: I use atmel studio, that gives me the same error as the previous answer:
pasting ")" and "__" does not give a valid preprocessing token & too few arguments to the function GPIO_Init

Comment: Yes, that is the case, PORTA is indeed defined in the included files. I think I have no hope getting that to work. :(

Comment: Just don't use PORTA__ and stuff for your names, but something like `PortA`, or other non-conflicting scheme.

Answer (score 1):

The usual technique for this is to add a level of indirection, like this:

```
#define PORTNAME(port)     port ## __
#define initPort(port, mask, dir, pullup) GPIO_Init(PORTNAME(port), mask, dir, pullup)

typedef enum {
    PORTA__,
    PORTB__,
    PORTC__,
    PORTD__
} PORT;

void GPIO_Init(PORT p, uint8_t pins, Direction dir, uint8_t pullup)
{
    switch (p)
    {
    case PORTA__:
        break;
    }
}

#define LED_PORT PORTA
initPort(LED_PORT, 1, 9, 43)
```

This can be preprocessed (I ran `cpp port31.c` to get this output):

```
# 1 "port31.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "port31.c"




typedef enum {
    PORTA__,
    PORTB__,
    PORTC__,
    PORTD__
} PORT;

void GPIO_Init(PORT p, uint8_t pins, Direction dir, uint8_t pullup)
{
    switch (p)
    {
    case PORTA__:
        break;
    }
}


GPIO_Init(PORTA__, 1, 9, 43)
```

This looks like the result you are after.

There are other questions on SO which describe the general technique.

Comment: I actually tried that before posting the question but I get an error: 
pasting ")" and "__" does not give a valid preprocessing token. along with some more errors and warnings: 
too few arguments to function GPIO_Init

Comment: Yes, I got some similar errors when I tried: `#define EVALUATE(x) x` and `#define initPort(port, mask, dir, pullup) GPIO_Init(EVALUATE(port) ## __, mask, dir, pullup)`.  It doesn't work, so I didn't show it as an 'answer'.  The concatenation must be in what I showed as the `PORTNAME` macro.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is impossible. However, you can create a function called LED_PORTinitPort() and call that by concatentating the first argument of the macro to initPort(), which acheives the same goal.